# BEX error c0000417 VC++ and MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I had access, via a friend, to a vc++ code which has MFC components with AxisMediaControl object to stream and record videos from an IP camera.

Now I am a complete novice in MFC and VC++. But I was going through the code as I know some C++ and was trying out if I could catch some MFC. It was probably a wrong choice starting with a complex application.

But nevertheless, in brief the application has three AFX threads running, one to read I/O from a hardware, One which implements some logic based on these I/O inputs and one which looks for any change in configuration of these I/O pins - It has a shared memory open and reads if there is any content in that shared memory and saves the content as a file.

Based on the I/O this application and the second thread mentions starts playing then records video from an IP camera.

When I run the application after compiling in VS2010, it runs as a standalone application as an exe for some random time and then I see a **BEX** error.

> Log Name:      Application Source:        Application Error Date:
>   1/20/2015 1:50:59 PM Event ID:      1000 Task Category: (100) Level:
>   Error Keywords:      Classic User:          N/A Computer:      ITSME
>   Description: Faulting application name: Video.exe, version: 1.0.0.1,
>   time stamp: 0x54bcf6f8 Faulting module name: Video.exe, version:
>   1.0.0.1, time stamp: 0x54bcf6f8 **Exception code: 0xc0000417** Fault offset: 0x001256cd Faulting process id: 0x608 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d03489d809fe4d Faulting application path:
>   D\iRIDSClient\bin\Video.exe Faulting module path:
>   D\iRIDSClient\bin\Video.exe Report Id:
>   42d67f3f-a07d-11e4-8756-00306421c6e4 Event Xml: 
>   
>       
>       1000
>       2
>       100
>       0x80000000000000
>       
>       8427
>       Application
>       ITSME
>             
>       Video.exe
>       1.0.0.1
>       54bcf6f8
>       Video.exe
>       1.0.0.1
>       54bcf6f8
>       c0000417
>       001256cd
>       608
>       01d03489d809fe4d
>       D:\iRIDSClient\bin\Video.exe
>       D:\iRIDSClient\bin\Video.exe
>       42d67f3f-a07d-11e4-8756-00306421c6e4    .

I got this from the windows event logger. 
I am not pasting the code here as I wont be able to comprehend code related suggestions. Could anybody please give an idea on what situations can this error code occur. Where can I start to solve this error. I know this is unauthorized memory access error. But WHAT operation(s) could cause it? Please help.

Comment: Launch the application in the Debugger. You should get a stop at the location with the bug. Look into the stack trace.

Comment: @xMRi Thanks for the reply. But the problem is to run the application I need to have H/W access to the machine in which I am running. I cannot run or install IDE on that. Otherwise I could have tried that option.

Can you please suggest where or what operations in code COULD trigger this. Even a general idea would be fine. I read DEP and c0000417 on msdn site. But that didnt give any idea about what C++ code could cause this.

Comment: User remote Debugging. Ist easy.

Comment: A 0x0000417 error code is indicative of _An invalid parameter was passed to a C runtime function._  The crash must have produced a dump file (.dmp).  Collect that dump file and perform postmortem debugging.